# Create PreferenceDialog onClick on filter popup?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-preferences, android-dialogfragment

**My goal is to implement the image below.**

How to create a PreferenceDialog if the filter icon in my toolbar has been clicked?

I want to set some preferences to filter the entries of my list.

[I'm at this point.](http://pastebin.com/eKNWtrQE) Is that the right way to implement this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes sir, it is!

You should inflate the resource first and set it as a custom view.
AlertDialog should do the trick after that. Do you have any further question? Or do you only need to check if it's the right way to do it?

Comment: It would be awsome, if you write a detailed guide about it! This should be a good place for it :)