# Create Custom Preference Items? Tutorial?

Tags: java, android, android-preferences

[2Dee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1178337/2dee) indicated me that my question wasn't conform to the rules. Let me have a new try ;)

> **[What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)**
>
> 2. Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

---

I need to add the following features to my custom preference:

- `[1]` Make the title-color programmatically editable or disableable
- `[2]` Make the icon-color programmatically editable or disableable
- `[3]` Add a <kbd>OK</kbd> button to the dialog

[image: IMG]
**Mirrors: [1](http://www.img-host.de/bild.php/57104,szguyVHB21.png), [2](http://abload.de/img/szguygkspz.png), [3](http://img5.fotos-hochladen.net/uploads/szguyp5zurf8s4i.png), [4](https://img5.picload.org/image/ipiaoag/szguy.png), [5](http://s15.postimg.org/iiuds877v/Sz_GUy.png), [6](http://v00.imgup.net/SzGUye6b5.png), [7](http://www.bilderload.com/daten/szguySV06Z.png)**

What has to be added to the `MultiIconListPreference-Class`? I couldn't find a guide for a general exaplaination.. That is the reason why asked unspecialised.

---

### Where I stuck:

```
// R.styleable.IconPreference +
// R.styleable.IconPreference_icon1 +
// R.styleable.IconPreference_entryIcons1 (res/values/attrs.xml)
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="IconPreference">
        <attr name="icon1" format="reference" />
        <attr name="entryIcons1" format="reference" />
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
 
// res/layout/list_item_dialog_pref.xml
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/image_list_view_row_table_layout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:paddingLeft="6dp"
    android:paddingStart="6dp"
    android:paddingRight="6dp"
    android:paddingEnd="6dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
 
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_item_dialog_pref_textview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="?android:textColorPrimary"
        android:layout_weight="0.95"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"/>
 
    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckBox
        android:id="@+id/list_item_dialog_pref_checkbox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
 
// res/layout/preference_icon.xml
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:padding="?android:attr/scrollbarSize">
 
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
 
        <TextView
            android:id="@+android:id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="?attr/android:textColorPrimary"
            android:textSize="16sp" />
 
        <TextView
            android:id="@+android:id/summary"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@android:id/title"
            android:layout_alignStart="@android:id/title"
            android:layout_below="@android:id/title"
            android:maxLines="2"
            android:textSize="14sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
 
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginRight="3dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
 
// res/xml/preference.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
   
    <PreferenceCategory>
        <com.android.app.MultiIconListPreference
            android:key="item_key"
            android:summary="@string/item_key_sum"
            android:title="@string/item_key"/>
    </PreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>
 
// com.android.app.MultiIconListPreference.java
public class MultiIconListPreference extends ListPreference {
    private Drawable mIcon;
    private IconListPreferenceScreenAdapter iconListPreferenceAdapter = null;
    private Context mContext;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private CharSequence[] entries;
    private CharSequence[] entryValues;
    private int[] mEntryIcons = null;
    private SharedPreferences prefs;
    private SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    private String mKey;
    private int selectedEntry = -1;
 
    public MultiIconListPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }
 
    public MultiIconListPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setLayoutResource(R.layout.preference_icon);
        mContext = context;
 
        TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.IconPreference, defStyle, 0);
        mIcon = a.getDrawable(R.styleable.IconPreference_icon1);
 
        int entryIconsResId = a.getResourceId(R.styleable.IconPreference_entryIcons1, -1);
        if (entryIconsResId != -1) {
            setEntryIcons(entryIconsResId);
        }
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        mKey = getKey();
        prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext());
        editor = prefs.edit();
 
        a.recycle();
    }
 
    @Override
    public String getValue() {
        if (selectedEntry != -1)
            return entryValues[selectedEntry].toString();
        return super.getValue();
    }
 
    @Override
    public void onBindView(View view) {
        super.onBindView(view);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        if (imageView != null && mIcon != null) {
            imageView.setImageDrawable(mIcon);
        }
    }
 
    public void setIcon(Drawable icon) {
        if ((icon == null && mIcon != null) || (icon != null && !icon.equals(mIcon))) {
            mIcon = icon;
            notifyChanged();
        }
    }
 
    public Drawable getIcon() {
        return mIcon;
    }
 
    public void setEntryIcons(int[] entryIcons) {
        mEntryIcons = entryIcons;
    }
 
    public void setEntryIcons(int entryIconsResId) {
        TypedArray icons_array = mContext.getResources().obtainTypedArray(entryIconsResId);
        int[] icon_ids_array = new int[icons_array.length()];
        for (int i = 0; i < icons_array.length(); i++) {
            icon_ids_array[i] = icons_array.getResourceId(i, -1);
        }
        setEntryIcons(icon_ids_array);
        icons_array.recycle();
    }
 
    @Override
    protected void onPrepareDialogBuilder(Builder builder) {
        super.onPrepareDialogBuilder(builder);
 
        entries = getEntries();
        entryValues = getEntryValues();
 
        if (entries.length != entryValues.length) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("ListPreference requires an entries array and an entryValues array which are both the same length");
        }
 
        if (mEntryIcons != null && entries.length != mEntryIcons.length) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("MultiIconListPreference requires the icons entries array be the same length than entries or null");
        }
 
        iconListPreferenceAdapter = new IconListPreferenceScreenAdapter(mContext);
 
        if (mEntryIcons != null) {
            String selectedValue = prefs.getString(mKey, "");
            for (int i = 0; i < entryValues.length; i++) {
                if (selectedValue.compareTo((String) entryValues[i]) == 0) {
                    selectedEntry = i;
                    break;
                }
            }
            builder.setAdapter(iconListPreferenceAdapter, null);
 
        }
    }
 
    private class IconListPreferenceScreenAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        public IconListPreferenceScreenAdapter(Context context) {
 
        }
 
        public int getCount() {
            return entries.length;
        }
 
        class CustomHolder {
            private TextView text = null;
            private AppCompatCheckBox rButton = null;
 
            CustomHolder(View row, int position) {
                text = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.list_item_dialog_pref_textview);
                text.setText(entries[position]);
 
                rButton = (AppCompatCheckBox) row.findViewById(R.id.list_item_dialog_pref_checkbox);
                rButton.setId(position);
                rButton.setClickable(false);
                rButton.setChecked(selectedEntry == position);
 
                if (mEntryIcons != null) {
                    text.setText(" " + text.getText());
                    text.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(mEntryIcons[position], 0, 0, 0);
                }
            }
        }
 
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return null;
        }
 
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }
 
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View row = convertView;
            CustomHolder holder = null;
            final int p = position;
            row = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_dialog_pref, parent, false);
            holder = new CustomHolder(row, position);
 
            row.setTag(holder);
 
            // row.setClickable(true);
            // row.setFocusable(true);
            // row.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
            row.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    v.requestFocus();
 
                    Dialog mDialog = getDialog();
                    mDialog.dismiss();
 
                    MultiIconListPreference.this.callChangeListener(entryValues[p]);
                    editor.putString(mKey, entryValues[p].toString());
                    selectedEntry = p;
                    editor.commit();
                    editor.apply();
 
                }
            });
 
            return row;
        }
 
    }
}
```

Comment: I removed my vote to close and upvoted your question. Unfortunately, I'm at work, where our proxy blocks a lot of images, so I can't see your image. If I have some time when I get home, I'll have a look. In the meantime, it is usually better to include the code in the question itself rather than sharing a link to pastebin. After all, it is likely that all the code is not relevant to solve your issue, and that way, if the link goes dead for any reason at any time, future readers will still be able to understand the question. Best of luck for your investigation !

Comment: Image Mirrors: [1](http://www.img-host.de/bild.php/57104,szguyVHB21.png), [2](http://abload.de/img/szguygkspz.png), [3](http://img5.fotos-hochladen.net/uploads/szguyp5zurf8s4i.png), [4](https://img5.picload.org/image/ipiaoag/szguy.png), [5](http://s15.postimg.org/iiuds877v/Sz_GUy.png), [6](http://v00.imgup.net/SzGUye6b5.png), [7](http://www.bilderload.com/daten/szguySV06Z.png) `;)` I inclueded the code. Thats my nasty habit to use pastebin.. I working on it. Could you help me now? I'm on work too and stuck excatly on that point.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think I'm able to answer that question by myself :)
I found the `material-dialogs` on [GitHub](https://github.com/afollestad/material-dialogs) and used it in other parts of my application.
For example a filter:
[Create PreferenceDialog onClick on filter popup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31811381/create-preferencedialog-onclick-on-filter-popup)

I'm going to add a detailed explaination soon.